# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - when setting columnHeaders

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I created the following table. However, when running the sample program I get the following expection, at the line `tcm.getColumn(0).setHeaderValue(columnNames[0]);`:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(Unknown Source)
    at test.tableHeader.JTableRowHeader.<init>(JTableRowHeader.java:62)
    at test.tableHeader.JTableRowHeader$6.run(JTableRowHeader.java:169)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
com.passlogix.vgo.ho.WindowHandleException: null: javax.swing.JFrame[frame0,0,0,0x0,invalid,hidden,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,title=JTable,resizable,normal,defaultCloseOperation=HIDE_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@949f69,flags=16777609,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true]
    at com.passlogix.vgo.ho.ApplicationWindow.nativeGetWindowHandle(Native Method)
    at com.passlogix.vgo.ho.ApplicationWindowAccessJava1dot4.getHWnd(ApplicationWindowAccessJava1dot4.java:50)
    at com.passlogix.vgo.ho.WindowScanner.run(WindowScanner.java:569)
```

Here is a reproducible sample program:

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Component;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.EventQueue;
    import java.awt.Font;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTable;
    import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
    import javax.swing.UIManager;
    import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
    import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
    import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
    import javax.swing.event.RowSorterEvent;
    import javax.swing.event.RowSorterListener;
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
    import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
    import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;
    import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
    import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

    public class JTableRowHeader {

        private JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTable");
        private JScrollPane scrollPane;
        private JTable tableAnalytics;
        private DefaultTableModel model;
        private DefaultTableModel model1;
        private TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter;
        private JTable headerTable;
        private String[] columnNames = {"AVERAGE", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022", "2023"};
        private String[] rowNames = {"Production Costs", "Average Equity", "Debt Yield Percentage", "Sales Valuation"};


        public JTableRowHeader() {

            model1 = new DefaultTableModel() {
                /**
                 * UUID
                 */
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 8538648271391086030L;

                @Override
                public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                    return false;
                }
            };

            tableAnalytics = new JTable(rowNames.length, columnNames.length);
            tableAnalytics.setModel(model1);
            for (int i = 0; i < model1.getRowCount(); i++) {
                for (int ii = 0; ii < model1.getRowCount(); ii++) {
                    model1.setValueAt(i + ii, i, ii);
                }
            }
            TableColumnModel tcm = tableAnalytics.getColumnModel();        
            tcm.getColumn(0).setHeaderValue(columnNames[0]);//here I get the expection!
            tcm.getColumn(1).setHeaderValue(columnNames[1]);
            tcm.getColumn(2).setHeaderValue(columnNames[2]);
            tcm.getColumn(3).setHeaderValue(columnNames[3]);
            tcm.getColumn(4).setHeaderValue(columnNames[4]);
            tcm.getColumn(5).setHeaderValue(columnNames[5]);
            tcm.getColumn(6).setHeaderValue(columnNames[6]);
            tcm.getColumn(7).setHeaderValue(columnNames[7]);
            tcm.getColumn(8).setHeaderValue(columnNames[8]);
            tcm.getColumn(9).setHeaderValue(columnNames[9]);

            sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(tableAnalytics.getModel());
            tableAnalytics.setRowSorter(sorter);
            model = new DefaultTableModel() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 12312432141L;

                @Override
                public int getColumnCount() {
                    return 1;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public int getRowCount() {
                    return tableAnalytics.getRowCount();
                }

                @Override
                public Class<?> getColumnClass(int colNum) {
                    switch (colNum) {
                    case 0:
                        return String.class;
                    default:
                        return super.getColumnClass(colNum);
                    }
                }
            };
            headerTable = new JTable(model);

            headerTable.setValueAt(rowNames[0], 0, 0);
            headerTable.setValueAt(rowNames[1], 1, 0);
            headerTable.setValueAt(rowNames[2], 2, 0);
            headerTable.setValueAt(rowNames[3], 3, 0);

            headerTable.setShowGrid(false);
            headerTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
            headerTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(50, 0));
            headerTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(50);
            headerTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new TableCellRenderer() {
                @Override
                public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable x, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

                    boolean selected = tableAnalytics.getSelectionModel().isSelectedIndex(row);
                    Component component = tableAnalytics.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer().getTableCellRendererComponent(tableAnalytics, value, false, false, -1, -2);
                    ((JLabel) component).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                    if (selected) {
                        component.setFont(component.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
                        component.setForeground(Color.red);
                    } else {
                        component.setFont(component.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));
                    }
                    return component;
                }
            });
            tableAnalytics.getRowSorter().addRowSorterListener(new RowSorterListener() {
                @Override
                public void sorterChanged(RowSorterEvent e) {
                    model.fireTableDataChanged();
                }
            });
            tableAnalytics.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                    model.fireTableRowsUpdated(0, model.getRowCount() - 1);
                }
            });
            scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tableAnalytics);
            scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(headerTable);
            tableAnalytics.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(tableAnalytics.getPreferredSize());
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(scrollPane);

            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocation(150, 150);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    JTableRowHeader TestTableRowHeader = new JTableRowHeader();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I now tried to create my Column headers dynamically, with:

```
    TableColumnModel tcm = tableAnalytics.getColumnModel();  
    for (int k = 0; k < tcm.getColumnCount(); k++) {
        tcm.getColumn(k).setHeaderValue(columnNames[k]);
    }
```

instead of:

```
    tcm.getColumn(0).setHeaderValue(columnNames[0]);
    tcm.getColumn(1).setHeaderValue(columnNames[1]);
    tcm.getColumn(2).setHeaderValue(columnNames[2]);
    tcm.getColumn(3).setHeaderValue(columnNames[3]);
    tcm.getColumn(4).setHeaderValue(columnNames[4]);
    tcm.getColumn(5).setHeaderValue(columnNames[5]);
    tcm.getColumn(6).setHeaderValue(columnNames[6]);
    tcm.getColumn(7).setHeaderValue(columnNames[7]);
    tcm.getColumn(8).setHeaderValue(columnNames[8]);
    tcm.getColumn(9).setHeaderValue(columnNames[9]);
```

However, I still get the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem in next:

You create `JTable` with rows/columns:

`tableAnalytics = new JTable(rowNames.length, columnNames.length);`

but then you override model `tableAnalytics.setModel(model1);` with rows=0/columns=0, because of you get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Create your `JTable` like next:

```
    DefaultTableModel  model1 = new DefaultTableModel(rowNames.length, columnNames.length) {
         /**
          * UUID
          */
         private static final long serialVersionUID = 8538648271391086030L;

         @Override
         public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
             return false;
         }
     };

     JTable  tableAnalytics = new JTable(model1);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is your initialization of `rowNames`:

```
private String[] rowNames = {"Production Costs", "Average Equity", "Debt Yield Percentage", "Sales Valuation"};
```

This array has only 4 elements, so `rowNames[4]` is out of bounds. The valid indices are 0 to 3.

Comment: Thx for your answer!I guess, this error will follow, after fixing the described error. I now fixed it in my question, because it does not fix the described error. I would appreciate your input on my question!